What is causation?
I suppose the common idea of “causation” to me seems like it is supposed to reduce to physical causation, at least this is a standard worldview in modern times. In other words, the implied metaphysics is, “all human (cognitive, social) phenomena are explainable in terms of neuronal systems (brains, the nervous system), which is fully explainable in terms of chemistry and physics.” The idea of Laplace’s daemon is about how the essential logicalness of the world means that explanations for “high-level” or “complex” phenomena 100% reduce or translate to the logical elements of the world; similar to a computer.
It seems like it is also very easy to reduce “time” to something mathematical. And generally, while we can express “time” inside of logic, we generally take the “truth” of propositions to not require a temporal dimension. That is to say, it seems (conventionally) feasible to describe time in terms of something atemporal (logical statements, like “At time 3:00 p.m., Sally went to the muffin store.”), so that we can easily factor out time in an attempt to completely describe “the world”: it’s just another numerical parameter in a system of many numerical parameters.
This is the conventional view, to me, anyway.
I think what this would mean is that there is no need for the idea of “causality”. If physics reduces to logic, then “causality” is just the idea of “logical necessity” framed in terms of physical laws and physical data. To say “a billiard ball travels forward and hits another one, causing the second one to move forward”, is just to say “if something called “matter” occupies a point in a certain numerical space, there are laws regarding how certain numerical properties change as a function of other numerical properties.” We can still think sequentially about events, but they could be expressed as logical implication: “Ball X is at point Y with momentum Z implies Ball A moves with momentum B at time C”.
I’m not certain this is correct, but I’m interested in any deep reasons why trying to reduce the world to logical models has its limits. Can anyone provide a really strong argument why the whole category of “causality” could not be eliminated and just be reduced to “logical necessity”? Or, otherwise, if we say something causes something, we actually mean it was a logical consequence, not a “physical” one.

I generally agree with you. There is no strong argument, that's why your question will probably be closed.

Your "question" - and the way you put it - is the most fundamental question in philosophy. But nowdays to question causation, is The taboo.

Physics does not reduce to logic. Anyway, if we bypass physicsl necessity that way, we are left with logical necessity and the issue is still there: why?

You seem to making a mistake common to people (mostly men) who think in very abstract terms. The mistake you are making is thinking that because you have a useful or interesting abstraction of a physical phenomenon, that you can therefore dispense with the phenomenon itself. But the mere fact that you can abstract physical events without a term corresponding to causality does not mean that actual physical events can dispense with causality.

@David Gudeman, This answer is not understandable by me, can you rephrase?

@IoannisPaizis, I'm referring to sentences like this: "it seems (conventionally) feasible to describe time in terms of something atemporal" Just because you can find a description that doesn't refer to time doesn't imply that time doesn't exist. Your model or description of the real world is not the real world. The process of abstraction, by its very nature, leaves out details; that's the whole point of abstraction. So it makes no sense to suggest that since you have an abstraction that leaves something out, that that thing does not exist at all.

@David Gudeman, Ok, but you have not commented on the main issue, how you see causation.

Causality as a fundamental property of (physical) reality is a misconception of logos. What we witness as causality in the physical layer is just the manifestation of logos as a serialized (in time) process of expressing itself. Let me explain with a simple example: A seed will become a tree if favorable conditions as met or unfavorable conditions will not prevent the outcome. No matter how many parameters you objectify in order to explain the process (ex. temperature, water, minerals e.t.c.) and no matter how you "arrange" events (causes) in time, the process has its own dynamics (logos) and the desired result (teleology) will be accomplished (entelechy) if conditions allow it. The objectification of this process, what someone thinks of as causality (the specific events that took place) are just the tips of the icebergs, literally. What is really going on, is under the sea.

The universe follows certain behavioral patterns that we can't directly express, because we don't know its internals.
However, we have discovered certain rules that fit natural behavior, if and only if they are based on certain abstractions. Such set of rules is known as Logic, and it is strongly related to language; so we can say that the core of Logic is propositional logic.
This means that if we can abstract what atoms do as concepts, logic describes the universe. For example, instead of describing millions of millions of atoms and interactions, we can just abstract such pattern as "it rains", and use such abstraction in logical rules: when it rains, plants get water. Applying the rule tollendo, we can describe facts of the the universe we didn't experienced: "since plants didn't get water, it didn't rain".
Causality is just one rule more among such rational abstraction mechanism: it just relates sequential facts. See this rule: if brakes are pressed, the car stops. In nature, there's no brakes, cars or pressure. But in our mental realm of abstraction, there is.

logic comes from logos, which is not bound by rules, rules are abstractions, nature is not. What you refer as logic is a misconception and misinterpretation and mistranslation of the initial greek term.
